# IE9 dynamic-page JS issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dynamic-loading

I've created a page which utilizes dynamic page loading with JS, it works fine in Safari, FF and Chrome - But of course the infamous Internet Explorer isn't doing a good job.

(I know there are other issues on this page, under the "Cykler" section, these aren't important for this question and shouldn't be focused at)

http://soegaardcykler.dk/beta

Try clicking on one of the categories, Cykler, Info and so on.

The strange thing is that if I open developer tools in IE and set the mode to IE8 and back to IE9 there is no issue, it switches pages like any of the other browsers.

If I close and open IE again the issue is back - If I go to the console to check what's going on it asks me to refresh the page - When I do this the issue is gone again.

I have no idea what the heck is going on, two of my friends have tested as well and they both have the issue when coming to the page for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I notice you're logging to a console.  That's problematic in IE.  The console object only shows up if the console is actually open (I think).

There are several solutions out there to avoid console issues; I can't recommend a best practice though besides creating your own logger object (which isn't a bad idea anyway).

Just a side node:  I don't know if you're using a Windows operating system, but if you're familiar with the Fiddler2 HTTP traffic analyzer, you can search through sessions really easily.  That's how I found the file you missed.

One last edit:  here's a good related post: [What's the correct way to write to the script console (console.log) in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4324454/whats-the-correct-way-to-write-to-the-script-console-console-log-in-ie)

Comment: I removed the logging, but it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: I removed the debugger console in IE and it's working for me.

Comment: well dangit.  I tried restarting IE and it's no longer working. I'm still betting it's that console object being invoked somewhere else though.  You can do more to the console than just log.

Comment: You're right - I removed that as well - Can you test again? Seems to work on my side now.