# JavaScript: Why isn't console considered a standard built-in object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

`console` is not included in [the list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects), but is pretty much available to use in any environment.

On a side note, why isn't `console` capitalized like every other built-in global object like `Number` or `Array`?

Comment: `Number` and `Array` are constructor functions. `console` is a Web API, it's not a part of JS.

Comment: https://console.spec.whatwg.org/ says "For historical reasons, `console` is lowercased."

Comment: 1) Because it is not mentioned in the spec: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/ . 2) Maybe because it is not a constructor but a "normal" function?

Comment: @FelixKling It's not even a function, it's just a normal object (acting as namespace)

Comment: @Amadan: Whoops, somehow I thought about `console.log`. It's late, I'm tired :P

Comment: @Amadan This note is for the namespace definition using "console" and not "Console", not the exposed api on the `window` object. I've elaborated more in my answer

Comment: @Bamieh: It was an answer to another comment that was changed, saying that it's lowercase `console` because it's not a constructor function. But since you've drawn my attention to your elaboration, "All methods provided by the whatwg spec implementing the window interface are not capitalized" is not an explanation, since, as I've already had to note above, `console` is not a method.

Comment: @Bamieh: Also, `window.console` _is_ the namespace they're talking about. It is an object whose sole purpose is to group various console-related methods. They are not two different things, as you imply in 'This note is for the namespace definition using "console" and not "Console", not the exposed api on the `window` object'.

Comment: @Amadan Agreed, they are not capitalized because they are not constructor functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ECMA-262 doesn't define `console` because ECMA-262 has no concept of I/O. Simply each browser implements/injects its own `console` implementation.

The [console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console) object was first introduced by browser debugging tools, Firebug was the first to try to formulate a consistent standard for the console api.

The [WHATWG](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/) (Web Hypertext Application Technology Working Group) has an early work in progress `console` spec to define the semantics of the console APIs, in an attempt to create convergence across environments.

> `console` is not included in [the list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects), but is pretty much available to use in any environment.

The `console` object is somehow consistent between browsers due to the following:

- Browsers and Node.js all individually follow the WHATWG console spec.
- Chrome extends *WebKit* which is also used by Safari.
- Node.js is built on top of *V8*, which defines the [console API](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/builtins/builtins-console.cc) used by node.

Currently many of the `console` methods are cross-browser compatible, however this was not always the case. Check the [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Browser_compatibility) to see the differences.

Arguably, each `console` implementation differs based on the environment it is served in, (chips, servers, browsers, etc.). Hence it does not make complete sense to have it standardized in ECMA.

Just like other browser specific APIs, the `console` is injected to javascript to give developers access to the browser API, such as `Node` and `Document`.

Here is a list of the complete [web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) injected into javascript to be accessible in JS code on the browser.

> why isn't `console` capitalized like every other built-in global object?

All methods provided by the whatwg spec implementing the `window` interface are **not capitalized** ([Check the window interface](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#the-window-object)), Since non of those methods are constructor functions.

It is also mentioned in the [spec](https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#namespacedef-console) that the `console` is lowercased due to historical reasons. However this note is talking about the *namespace definition* using "console" instead of "Console" used in the spec and **NOT** the exposed API.

---

*FUN FACT*: I remember the time when the `console` used to throw an error if the [debugger was not opened](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4324869/5384679) on IE.

Comment: Great answer! If I may offer a few corrections: 1) ECMA-262 doesn't define `console` because ECMA-262 has no concept of I/O. 2) browsers and node all individually follow the whatwg console spec, not by browsers happening to be built on other browsers as you suggest. 3) whatwg console spec is already ratified, so no need to use future tense "will be part of the whatwg spec"

Comment: @snek thank you! 1) You are correct, please feel free to update the answer. 2) I referred to this line in the spec "This specification is an early work in progress" But indeed it is part of the spec (updated answer).

Comment: @snek Surely the `console` implementations of the different environments converged before it became a whatwg standard - either because implementations inherited from each other or because they followed [the standard set by the Firebug extension](https://web.archive.org/web/20171214102729/https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Console_API) (unfortunately no longer online). Here's a bit of history overview: http://2ality.com/2013/10/console-api.html

Comment: @Bergi definitely. the clarification i was trying to make is that chrome and safari and node.js etc all have the same console interface *today* because they all willfully follow the same spec. it isn't just because of historical copycat reasons.